# drawImage from MediaSource video to canvas not showing image in Safari

Tags: canvas, safari, html5-video, drawimage, media-source

drawImage from MediaSource video to canvas not showing image in Safari 11.1 ([Example](http://readme.link/test/safari_video_mse.html): video and canvas). When using url to video instead of MediaSource (set video.src) then image drawn on canvas ([Example](http://readme.link/test/safari_video_src.html)). 
There is no problem in other browsers. In Safary Technology Preview, the problem is also present.

In WebKit tracker there is [Bug 125157](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=125157), he is marked as fixed, but he is reproduced in Safari 11.1.

Is there any way to draw MediaSource video to canvas in Safari?

Comment: did you ever get to the bottom of this? Just coming across this very same issue now... two years later !?

Comment: This is still a Safari issue. I created a bug in their tracker, they gave a link to some internal tracker. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=186038

Comment: There is more fresh bugs from another peoples: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206812